# Formula of Variance of the difference for two dependent t-test

Tags: variance, t-test

having this equation for the variance of a sample of a two dependent t-test:

$$
s^{2}_{d} =   \frac{{\sum(x_i-\overline{x})}^2}{{n-1}}
$$

with $d$ being the difference between the two paired variables

I'm trying to figure out why the variance of the difference can be written in the next form.

$$
s^{2}_{d} = \frac{\sum{d^2}-\frac{(\sum{d})^2}{n}}{n-1}
$$

how to pass from this: ${\sum(x_i-\overline{x})}^2$ to this $\sum{d^2}-\frac{(\sum{d})^2}{n}$

I think that maybe I am missing a mathematical concept. Can you help me with this, please?

Thanks

Comment: Please, what is $d$ in your second formula?

Comment: You want to have an index on $d$ and note that since the $x$'s are the differences in the first formula, $d_i=x_i$, the rest is *really* simple algebra.

Comment: Start by displaying the square in $\sum_i (x_i - \bar x)^2$ as $x_i^2 -2\bar x(x_i) + \bar x^2.$ Apply the sum to each term, recalling that $\bar x =\frac 1 n \sum_i x_i.$. Use $\sum_i ax_i = a\sum_i x_i$ and $\sum_i \bar x = n\bar x.$